# HandsOnTable context menu: how to make it work with web2py data?

Tags: web2py, handsontable

The contextMenu of HandsOnTable seems problematical when used with web2py. If the data source is an array in the script, the context menu works; if the data source is anything else - i.e., from web2py -, the context menu does not work. For example:

When I instantiate a HandsOnTable with this, the context menu works:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
var data = [
        {
            "id":1,
            "last_name":"Abbrederis",
            "first_name":"Jason",
            "pos":"WR"

        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "last_name":"Abbrederis",
            "first_name":"Jason",
            "pos":"WR"
        },
        {
            "id":3,
            "last_name":"Adams",
            "first_name":"Davante",
            "pos":"WR"
        }
        ];

var hotElement = document.getElementById('list');
datatable = new Handsontable(hotElement, {
    data: data,
    contextMenu: ['row_above','row_below','remove_row','undo','redo'],

    <snip other table configuration>
```

However, if I instantiate the table with this (in a web2py app), the table builds correctly and the context menu shows all the items, but "Insert row above" and "Insert row below" are disabled and grayed-out. (The data comes from the web2py function calling this view, and is a standard web2py database retrieval.)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

var data = {{=XML(data.json())}}

var hotElement = document.getElementById('list');
datatable = new Handsontable(hotElement, {
    data: data,
    contextMenu: ['row_above','row_below','remove_row','undo','redo'],

    <snip other table configuration>
```

I recall seeing somewhere that this behavior is known, that the context menu works correctly only when the data for the table is an array. Is that correct? Are there any work-arounds to make the context menu work as it should in a web2py app?

Comment: Assuming `data` is a web2py `Rows` object, `data.json()` will be exactly what you need (i.e., an array of records in JSON format). I suggest you look at the final rendered HTML and see if the JSON looks incorrect in any way.

Comment: Can you give a try by making contextMenu: true

Comment: Thanks for the response, Anthony..

Anthony: the JSON looks fine in HTML. I believe this is a HandsOnTables problem, as the table renders perfectly and would not, I think, if the JSON were messed up.

Comment: Thanks, Mazzu. I've used two contextmenu lines: `contextmenu = true`, and `contextmenu = ["row_above","row_below","remove_row"]`. In both cases, the menu works correctly when the data is specified as an array in the javascript function, but disables "Insert row above" and "Insert row below" when the comes via web2py. I translate the web2py array with `data = {{=XML(data.json())}}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem had nothing to do with web2py or HandsOnTables; it was my misunderstanding about how maxRows works. I had maxRows set to a value and the dataset had more rows than the maxrows value. So, of course, no more rows can be added to the table, and the add_row functions don't work.  By removing the maxrows value, it worked as it should. My mistake...